# How to copy multiple URLs to the clipboard?

Tags: swift, macos, nspasteboard

I have an array of URLs that I want to copy to the clipboard:

```
let urls = [URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,  URL(string: "https://www.microsoft.com")!]
```

I've tried the following:

```
NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects(urls as [NSURL])
```

However, that only copies the first URL to the clipboard.

This also only copies the first url:

```
for url in urls {
    NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects([url as NSPasteboardWriting])
}
```

The following code works, but only copies the strings. If other apps read the pasteboard, they will find strings, but not URLs:

```
let urlStrings = urls.compactMap { url in
     url.absoluteString
}
for urlStrig in urlStrings {
      NSPasteboard.general.writeObjects([urlStrig as NSPasteboardWriting])
}
```

I've tried  `NSPasteboard.general.prepareForNewContents()` and  `NSPasteboard.general.clearContents`  before writing to the pasteboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your issue might be that the receiving app doesn't know what to do with an array of urls. What app are you pasting in? Does it seem to handle a list of urls from other apps?

Comment: maybe it wants them in a single string.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Just be sure to call `clearContents()` before calling `writeObjects` with the array of URLs (as `[NSURL]`). Then reading them back using `NSPasteboard.general.readObjects(forClasses: [NSURL.self])` gives back the full array. Tested in both a macOS Swift Playground and an AppKit app running under macOS 13.2.1.